# Standarised Validation and Error checking C#

Tags: c#, validation, logging, input, error-handling

I am currently developing a project which handles a lot of types of inputs which have constraints like a double being between 0 and 1. I am thinking of validating this input in a standardised way by using a class which I would call to validate the input and if the input was wrong would throw out a result to a log file or throw an exception.

tl;dr : Is there a good method to standardise validation across a program which uses a log file.

Example:

```
        public void AddTimes(double time1, double time2)
        {
            if (time1 < 0)
            {
                ErrorManager.Validation_MustBeNonNegative(ErrorManager.GetName(new { time1 }), time1.ToString());
            }
            else if (time2 <= 0)
            {
                ErrorManager.Validation_MustBeNonNegativeNonZero(ErrorManager.GetName(new { time1 }), time2.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide the codes before someone can actually help you with your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use log4net to do the logging from your custom method.  Configuring and logging to log4net is a well documented topic on SO and so you should refine your question and search again.

To validate your value, you need to have a way of expressing the valid range.  Microsoft includes some range checking features in it's frameworks, but you can easily roll your own:

```
public static void AssertTimesAreValid(double time1, double time2)
{
                if (time1 < 0)
        {
            ErrorManager.Validation_MustBeNonNegative(ErrorManager.GetName(new { time1 }), time1.ToString());
            throw new ArgumentException("Times are not far enough apart.");
        }
        else if (time2 <= 0)
        {
            ErrorManager.Validation_MustBeNonNegativeNonZero(ErrorManager.GetName(new { time1 }), time2.ToString());
            throw new ArgumentException("Times are not far enough apart.");
        }
}

public void AddTimes(double time1, double time2)
{
    AssertTimesAreValid(time1, time2)

    // Do your work now
}
```

Your ErrorManager will need to do the logging.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it certainly covers the logging part of the question, although I would also like a system where I can just call a method and put a variable into it to see if it is valid or not (i.e. between 0 and 1) but log4net solves half the problem.

Comment: Updated to include example of range checking.